# Windows 7 doesn't recognize AVAST! antivirus

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, avast, security-warning

After upgrading to windows 7, I keep getting windows 7 Security warning:

> Windows did not find an antivirus software on this computer

what can I do to convince it AVAST s there?

*Details:*
* AVAST 4.8 home edition
* Windows 7 Ultima 64 bit

Comment: what version are you using

Comment: Not making this as an answer as it doesn't actually help your problem, but before you install Avast, I highly recommend you test Microsoft Security Essentials. As a independent tester, I am **very** happy with everything I have seen from this product and if you want a free AV solution, I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the 64-bit version didn't get installed. According to [Avast's webpage](http://www.avast.com/eng/avast-free-home-antivirus-antispyware.html):

> **Support for 64-bit Windows**
>
> avast! Home/Professional now fully
>   supports the 64-bit Windows platform.
>   ALWIL Software is anticipating massive
>   take-up of this platform, as Windows
>   XP 64-Bit Edition will support up to
>   32 GB of RAM and 16 TB of virtual
>   memory, enabling applications to run
>   faster when working with large data
>   sets. Applications can preload
>   substantially more data into virtual
>   memory, allowing rapid access by the
>   64-bit extensions of the processor.
>   This reduces the time for loading data
>   into virtual memory or seeking,
>   reading, and writing to data storage
>   devices, making applications run
>   faster and more efficiently.
>
> Regular (32-bit) antivirus
>   applications are unable to operate
>   correctly on the 64-bit Windows
>   platform because they rely on 32-bit
>   kernel-mode drivers. The new avast!
>   uses native 64-bit drivers, delivering
>   the same level of protection as in the
>   32-bit Windows environments. *The
>   installation package is the same for
>   32-bit and 64-bit versions - the setup
>   program automatically detects the
>   operating system it is running on, and
>   installs all necessary files.* You may
>   find more information on [avast!
>   Antivirus and Windows x64 Edition
>   page](http://www.avast.com/eng/x64.html).

Note the sentence I emphasized - since you're running 4.8, which is the latest version, I would try uninstalling and reinstalling Avast. I used Avast 32-bit on Windows 7 until I found [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) (which I can confirm works perfectly with Windows 7 x64 and is free to boot!)

Comment: I've had no issues running Avast on Windows 7 x64